# Azure Auth Service not work after publishing

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api2, microsoft-graph-api

I have a .net Web API where I provide an endpoint for SPAs to get an Azure oAuth 2 access token. When I run the web api locally the service works fine. However, when I publish the service to MS Azure the endpoint returns me {"Message":"An error has occurred."}. The error is only thrown when I want to authenticate a user. If I run the same code for a client auth with client secret, an access token is returned correctly.

My question is, why does this happens only on azure and how can I fix it?

**User Auth** (not working on Azure)

The resource is for example: "https://graph.microsoft.com"

```
public string Get([FromUri] String resource)
        {
            var token = GetAuthenticatedUserAsync(resource).Result;
            return token.AccessToken;
        }
//Authentication of an user
[DisableCors()]
private static async Task<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult> GetAuthenticatedUserAsync(String resource)
        {
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize");
                return await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserClientId"], new Uri("{redirect url}"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

**Client Auth** (working on Azure)

```
//Authentication of a client
[DisableCors()]
public static async Task<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult> GetAuthenticatedAppAsync() 
{
  AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize");
  var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppClientSecret"]);
  return await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GraphResource"], credentials).ConfigureAwait(false);    
}
```

Comment: You can't use an overload with `PromptBehavior.Auto` if this is a back-end service. You need to take the access token sent by the SPA, and exchange that for an access token using the On-Behalf-Of flow.

Comment: @juunas thank you. Why does it works on localhost and not on azure?

Comment: That is actually a very good question :) I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, why does this happens only on azure and how can I fix it?

As juunas mentioned that we can't use the **PromptBehavior.Auto** way on the Azure WebApp.

It seems that **PromptBehavior** is a GDI+ behavior. As WebApp is [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). It is not allowed in the Azure WebApp.

If you want to authenticate and authorize users end-to-end in Azure App Service, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad) and this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication).